# Android Lint Check for specific project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, lint

I am using Android Studio for running custom lint check. I have created Custom Lint Library and after the build I am copying customlint.jar by

cp linte/build/libs/customlint.jar ~/.android/lint/

This will copy the customlint.jar to ~/.android/lint/ folder.

Now when I run lint its working as expected.

But when I open other sample projects the custom lint errors are appearing. How to avoid this?

Is there anyway so that customlint.jar is not copied ~/.android/lint/ folder and apply the custom lint checks only to my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have logged the same issue here

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233632

As per the reply this feature will be included in future sprints.

Note - Will edit this answer once it is included. Hence marking this as answer.